# axios response destructuring undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, destructuring

```
export async function downloadAndSyncData(
  user_id: number
): Promise<boolean> {
  try {
    const { status, data } = await getProtocols(user_id);
    let { sets } = data;
    if (status === 200) {
      if (sets !== undefined) {
        console.log("entrou aqui");
        sets.map(async set => {
          const callDetail = detailData(set);
          let obj = await insertDataStorage("DetailSchema", callDetail);
        });
      } else {
        console.log("undefined sets");
      }
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  } finally {
    await syncOptions();
  }
}
```

I have a function on my app that make a request from sets to show on a list.
sets is an Array of Objects, that comes from my backend on laravel.
[laravel return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7omt.png)

The thing is, sometimes that work, sometimes not. And i didn't understand why.
It works with small objects.

[test console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50krD.png)

On postman, its ok too.
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cEvw.png)

Comment: The thing is, there's always data on the tests. but somethimes the destructuring { sets } = data works, sometimes not. I tried sets = data.sets too, and try with let sets, let { sets }, ...., I just wanna understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move destructuring inside `if (status === 200) {` check. If the status is not 200 then the `data` might be undefined and you cannot destructure `undefined` value.

Or you can rewrite your check like that: `let sets = data?.sets;`, that way you will first check that the data is here, then get `sets` property value.

Comment: I tried it. The sets property is supposed to be an array. I put Array.isArray(sets) and the console is sometimes false, sometimes true.

Comment: When I tried limiting the response with few itens (less than 10) and works for all cases. But when i got more, 15 for example. Most of times return that isn't. But on response.data the JSON data is there.

Comment: Have you tried to log the `data` in the case when `sets` are undefined?

Comment: Yes! and data shows normal, she exists, but sets still undefined, and she is equal to the request in postman, where shows normally,

Comment: Well, that impossible. If you log the data before destructuring, and it's an object, then it should work fine. Maybe something wrong with your `getProtocols` function?